# how to implement Search Box and Pagination in Tiles aspx page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, promoted-links, tiles

I have used promoted link in SharePoint 2013 and have customized my page with my requirement using JavaScript. Now SharePoint doesn't provide OOTB search capability for tiles aspx page. Does anyone know how to create instant search (within the page) and pagination for tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used below mentioned code in CEWP above the list to search the result from the list & it worked fine for me in both SharePoint 2010 & SharePoint 2013.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElementsByCssClass(sTagName, sClassName) {
    var results = new Array();
    var allTagElements = document.getElementsByTagName(sTagName);
    for (i = 0; i < allTagElements.length; i++) {
        if(allTagElements[i].className == sClassName) results.push(allTagElements[i]);
    }
    return results;
}

function getTxt(obj) {
    if(obj.innerText) return obj.innerText;
    else return obj.textContent;
}

var lvRows = null;

function quickSearch(term) {
    if(lvRows == null) {
        var lvTable = getElementsByCssClass("table","ms-listviewtable")[0];
        lvRows = lvTable.childNodes[0].childNodes;
    }
    for(i = 1; i < lvRows.length; i++) {
        if(getTxt(lvRows[i]).toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            lvRows[i].style.display = "table-row";
        }
        else lvRows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
Quick Search: <input type="text" onkeyup="quickSearch(this.value)" class="ms-long"/>
```

**Note:-** It will only work for the single page is paging is enabled & more than one pages (of paging) in SharePoint list.

Kindly try it & let me know if any question...!

Comment: Didn't work for me bro, just have one text box and it's not working. I tried with normal list view though I am looking for tiles page

Comment: Can you please search the table name from the IE DOM & replace it here?

Comment: Please try this..http://developeratwar.com/2012/04/easy-list-filtering-in-sharepoint-with-jquery-quicksearch/

Comment: I have ms-listviewtable as class for normal list

Comment: Me too & mine is working.. Have you tried the solution in given link?

Comment: do I need to see anything apart from class name and how are you implement this to the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41713/discussion-between-hardik-and-rishabh-shukla).